# Summing data and adding it to a dictionary based on matching key

Tags: python

I have a dictionary for a person that contains data like age, weight etc.

```
{1665845: Person(1665845, 'Rurick', 101.00, 1.98, 75, 0),
 1294919: Person(1294919, 'Russel', 97.00, 1.90, 24, 0)}
```

In another list I have list of subsists containing `['key', 'date', 'data,...']`.
 The data is what the last item in the person dictionary is (which starts at 0).

```
[['1665845', '2001-01-06', '28,448,615,27,705'],
  ['1665845', '2001-01-10', '218,37,356,621,466,319,147,774,231,167,399,150,417,34,3'],
  ['1294919', '2001-01-04', '639,118,328,413,222,491,738,389,11,372,183,650,281,643,26,398,685,171'],
  ['1294919', '2001-01-10', '314,611,485,208,515,240,586,511,713,58,28,392,140,529,353,489,375,412,596'],
  ['1665845', '2001-01-04', '670,665,681,184,22,752,390,523,507,171,467,19,296,720,58,230,721,686'], 
  ['1665845', '2001-01-02', '432,210,732,204,771,555,448,82,343'],
  ['1294919', '2001-01-06', '113,225,564,554,392,544,313'],
  ['1294919', '2001-01-05', '437,219,239,545,588,303,477,384,87,254,429,635,188,372,572,712,383'],
  ['1294919', '2001-01-03', '771,373'],
  ['1294919', '2001-01-08', '650,679,492,524,202,689,224,268,195,455,400,235,518,505']]
```

If the key in the list of data matches the key of the person in the dictionary, I want to add the sum to that person. So for the above list I would end up with

```
{1294919 : Person(1294919, 'Russel', 97.00, 1.90, 24, 31022),
 1665845 : Person(1665845, 'Rurick', 101.00, 1.98, 75, 17701)}
```

Comment: so the data `'28,448,615,27,705'` is string so what it supposed to be?? are they individual list element or string?

Comment: yes, it could be say number of meters walked

Comment: can you write exactly how you need calculation of last element i.e. in key 1665845 how you are calculating or supposed to be calculate the value for last argument of person 17701

Comment: 17701 is the sum of all the data in those lists with the same key  (1665845)

Comment: What is `Person()`?

Comment: a class with a persons Id, weigh, height, age, and meters walked